# How to add an additional password to devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I need to add a second password field to devise. The original password will be used to login as usual. The second password will be used to "sign" documents.

Any ideas on how to implement this?

Comment: Is it important that the two passwords be distinct? I ask because this can be safely done using the account password.

Comment: @Substantial, yes both passwords must be distinct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just generate a migration specifying the data type as string.

1)`rails g migration AddPasswordToUser sign_password`

2)`rake db:migrate`

3) update the `user_params`

I would also use the gem bcrypt to get encrypt the password

https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby

Comment: I got the following error "Cannot find data type encrypted_password"

Comment: just edited my post. pass it a data type of string and use bcrypt to encrypt the password

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "signing documents" ?
Do you have a `Document` model ?
And a relation between `User` and `Document` ?

If yes, you should add the `password` on the `Document` model.